# UI5: Retrieve and display thousands of items in sap.m.Table

Tags: sapui5

There is a relational database (MySQL 8) with tens of thousands of items in the table, which need to be displayed in [`sap.m.Table`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Table). The straight forward approach is to retrieve all the items with SQL-query and to deliver it to the client-side in JSON in an async way. The key drawback of this approach is performance and memory consumption at the client-side. The whole table needs to be displayed on the client-side to provide user and ability to conduct fast searches. This is crucial for the app.

Currently, there are two options:

1. Fetch top 100 records and push them into the table. This way user can search the last 100 records immediately. At the same time to run an additional query in a web worker, which will take about 2…5 seconds and get all records except those 100. Then, to merge two JSONs.
2. Keep JSON on the application server as a cached variable and update it when the user adds a new record or deletes a record. Then I fetch the JSON which supposed to be much faster than querying the database.

How can I show in OpenUI5's `sap.m.Table` thousands of items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion;
You need to create OData backend for your tables. User can filter or search records with OData capabilities. You don't need to push all data to client, `sap.m.Table` automatically request rest of data with OData protocol while user scroll the table.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check how feasible the OData Backend option is.

Comment: The guidelines say you should use `sap.ui.table.Table` for very large sets. The recommendation is no more than 1000: https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/responsive-table/

Answer (score 1):

The SAP recommandation says max 100 datasets for `sap.m.Table`. In praxis, I would advise to follow the recommendation, even on fast PC the rendering will be slowed down.

If you want to test more than 100 datasets, you need to set the size limit on your `oModel` like `oModel.setSizeLimit(1000);`

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer you can`t.

Use [sap.ui.table](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Table) or provide a proper odata service with top/skip support as shown [here](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/) under 4.3 and 4.4.

Based on your backend code(java, abap, node) there are [libs](https://www.odata.org/libraries/) to help you.